# How can I create a json file from object with serializer?

Tags: json, symfony, object, serialization

This is my object $input:

```
$input = $this->em->getRepository(Data::class)->findAll();

  foreach($input as &$arr){
        $arr->{"Sunshine"} = 'Clouds';
    }
```

The output of $input:

```
Data {#1523 ▼
  -id: 23
  -name: "cat"
  -timestamp: DateTime @1570445917 {#1517 ▶}
  +"Sunshine": "Clouds"
}
```

I am using serializer to create a JSON file `$data`

```
  // Serialize your object in JSON
  $context = [
   'circular_reference_handler' => function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
      },
      'circular_reference_limit' => 0,
    ];

  $data = $serializer->serialize($input, 'json', $context);
```

$data:

```
"[{"id":21,"name":"cat","timestamp":"07.10.2019"}] ◀"
```

I wonder, why "Sunshine" is not in the JSON file. Does it have something to do with the `+`? What does `+` mean?

Comment: What is "Sunshine"? How are you producing the output you show with the `+`? What type of object is `$input`, an Entity, a \stdClass, what?

Comment: @ArleighHix I updated my question according to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're assigning the key incorrectly. A key should be assigned like this:

```
$arr['keyName'] = $value
```

You're assigning it like this:

```
$arr->{"keyName"} = $value
```

I hope I helped you with this answer!

Comment: Thank you! But when I test your advice, I am getting the error `Cannot use object of type App\Entity\Data as array`

Comment: Welp, that answer I just wrote. That's a big brainfart. You're retreiving all records in $input, after that you loop through every record with foreach. I don't understand what you're trying to do, but if you want every record in the database to contain the row 'Sunshine', you should edit your Entity with that information. I hope you can use this answer :)

Comment: Well Sunshine is a variable field, but in the end I want to show it in the same datatable, as if it is one enity. Do you know how I mean it? No it is not every record, this depends on the variable content

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to say. The way to achieve this is to create a new property in the Entity, and add a new field in the form which creates a new record. This way every record in your database can have a different value in the sunshine row.

Comment: But sometimes I do not want to add sunshine row. Sometimes it is a forest row, or nothing, or many others. Or is what you mean working like this? Can you give an example?

Comment: But in my example I perfectly added the row, why is it not visible in the json file. That is all I need

Comment: You could set the default value of those where you want nothing on null. I think you should read some articles about Doctrine and databases in general to get your head around this. 
Btw, the reason it is not visible, is because $arr->{"Sunshine"} refers to nothing